# SSIS data flow package connected to KISAM ODBC database unable to export yesterdays changes

Tags: ssis, odbc

I have an existing SSIS Package that is truncating SQL Server database tables before exporting all rows from selected tables in a KISAM database using KODBC 32bit drivers and a SQL Command in the data flow of:

```
select * from table_a
select * from table_b
etc
```

For the largest table, this is over 3.3 million rows with over 100 columns.  But less than 5,000 rows will change on any given day.

Due to business requirements, I can only run the package between 1am and 4am.  I have a working test package that is returning the expected 5,000 rows using:

```
Select * from table_a where table_a.date_column1=curdate()
```

That is giving me today's changed rows, but I need to be able to return yesterday's changed rows.

I have tried:

```
Select * from table_a where table_a.date_column1=(curdate(), INTERVAL -1, DAY)
```

,but get a syntax error as I think this may be MySQL or other ODBC syntax.

What is the correct syntax to get yesterday for Kerridge/Kisam ODBC?

Comment: If it is just syntax error, go to whatever tool you use to connect to the DB and run the query outside SSIS (always a good idea to test queries like this first) and then it will be much easier to narrow down your error.

Comment: Or just post your syntax error in your MYSQL in another channel that is not SSIS because this seems to be only a SQL ERROR outside SSIS.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Brad.  I don't have any means of directly accessing the Kerridge/KISAM ODBC database.  I have tried TSQL OPENQUERY and get data for yesterday's date, but only for one column in the Where clause (I need multiple columns) - SSIS package error is: Error at ODBC_Export_Numbers [ODBC_Export [2]]: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: '42000'. Native Error Code: 2174. [Kerridge][KISAM ODBC Driver][KISAM]syntax error in: ... der"
WHERE ("table".date_column=(curdate() >>> , <<<  INTERVAL -1 DAY) - removing the , just changes the error to >>>INTERVAL<<<

Comment: Looks completely proprietary.  You'll have better luck bumping into someone familiar with Kerridge over at dba.stackexchange.com.    Wild guess : where table_a.date_column1 - 0 = curdate() - 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `DATE_ADD()` function wich adds a time/date interval to a date and then returns the date :

```
 SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE table_a.date_column1=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

Comment: Hi Amira.  Thank you for your suggestion.  Unfortunately, I get a syntax error: Error at Job_ODBC_Export_Numbers [ODBC_Export [2]]: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) 

error occurred. state: '42000'. Native Error Code: 2174. [Kerridge][KISAM ODBC Driver]

[KISAM]syntax error in: ... eader"
WHERE ("table".date_column=DATE_ADD >>> ( <<< CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)

Comment: Thank you to everyone who commented and made suggestions. Unfortunately, nothing is working and the customer has allowed their support with the original database developers to lapse, so I am unable to take this any further.